# Aspect ratio is ignored with flex stretching items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have an item inside a flex container with a 1:1 aspect ratio set, with the items height intentionally left to be stretched to the height of the other flex items - it ignores the aspect ratio set.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="aspect-ratio: 1; background: blue">1:1</div>
  <h1>Blue box should have 1:1 aspect ratio</h1>
</div>
```

I've tried setting `width: min-content` and also manually overriding the height, but I want the height to be set by the flex stretch property.

Comment: Not sure if that _can_ work, because it easily creates a catch-22 type of situation. If the box in your example got _wider_, then the text next to it might need to break into more lines. So then your box would become _higher_, which in turn means to keep the aspect ratio, it would also have to become wider, _again_ ... Which could mean the text would need yet _another_ line ... etc. pp. The CSS specs are usually written in a way to prevent such situations from occurring in the first place.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. That said flex does have overflow built in so the text shouldn't wrap. What if instead of text it's am element with a fixed height?

Comment: _"That said flex does have overflow built in so the text shouldn't wrap."_ - the text in your given example is just the content of the `h1` element, and as such it will wrap _in there_.

Comment: Ah yes sorry in my build I have it overflowing. Ok but even so, what if the height of the other element is fixed

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

> If you want to maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio for the blue box while allowing its height to be stretched by the flex container, you can set the flex property along with a fixed width or use the min-width property on the box.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex: 1; aspect-ratio: 1; background: blue;">1:1</div>
  <h1>Blue box should have 1:1 aspect ratio</h1>
</div>
```

## Solution 2

> Setting min-width: 0 allows the box to shrink if necessary to maintain the aspect ratio.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="min-width: 0; aspect-ratio: 1; background: blue;">1:1</div>
  <h1>Blue box should have 1:1 aspect ratio</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are nice solutions, but what I really want is for the height set by the other flex items (in this case the heading), and then for the aspect ratio to calculate the width.

Comment: @daggett I suggest you use javascript to make this happen then.

Comment: Yeah it's a shame that this edge case isn't supported by the CSS spec

Comment: yeah, you could submit a request via w3c for support to the rfc for css3